# Custom query from all posts & all child page from one parent page?

Tags: wp-query

I'm working on a wordrpess site for improve search result. Now I want to fetch posts from a certain category & all child pages from one parent page.

If I set

```
post_parent => parent_id
```

then it only show all child pages, and not any posts(blog post).  But I want to show child pages from given id && blog posts. like:

```
post_parent=>parent_id && post_type=>post&&category=>array(cats id).
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this

Comment: By `&` there do you mean you actually want two sets of post for two different conditions in one query? It doesn't work like that.

Comment: Yes, actual, I want to show some blog post  from certain category & some child pages using parent page id but not all.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. As @Rarst said, you cannot do it in one query, wordpress doesn't work that way. You will have to run two queries. If you are not sure, file an [edit] and be more clear on what you actually need. Show some example, and the code that you have tried and why it is not working.